# connection.getContentLength() returns -1 in second time

Tags: android, stream, connection, urlconnection, android-download-manager

My stream link with content type of `application/octet-stream` returns -1 for below request in second time:

```
    URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
    URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
    int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
```

What is my code problem? problem is with my server? 
 
ADM in android & IDM in windows works with my link and detect size in the first. 
How can I solve this?

Comment: can u try with HTTPURLConnection class instead of URLConnection?

Comment: @Riad I tried this: `HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();` and got same result.

Comment: can u print the f_url value...and set HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);

Comment: print? What is your mean?

Comment: Where must I called this? : `HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);`. please provide some code.

Comment: "print" means see the value of the variable f_url[0].
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/ see here an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63301/discussion-between-riad-and-naruto-uzumaki).

Comment: I changed this `URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);` to `URL url = new URL(myurl);`